# I have a Java-React application hosted in AWS. Need to run it locally

Tags: java, reactjs, maven

I have a .war file downloaded from AWS. This code is actually running in production. I joined the team a week back and the developer who was working is not available now. No one in the company now have run the code locally. I downloaded the .war source code file from AWS. I have attached an image of what I see in Visual Code. I see a maven folder and it has a POM file. I am learning above Maven to run the application. but could not run it. I tried to run it with node js and failed.

I am very new to Node js and React.
Can anyone let me know how to make this code runnable locally?

[image]

Comment: Is it really node.js? Have you tried putting the war into the container? https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war

Comment: I am new to Jave, and node js. I have not done it. let me try that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like tomcat to run a war (or jetty) and you should be able to run the war logic on it.

Different ways to do it in tomcat: https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war